# How to delete the vowel from a given string

Tags: python-3.x

How to delete the vowel from the given string?

```py
letter = 'raeiou'
new_string = []
for i in letter:
    new_string.append(i)
for j in new_string:
    if j == 'a' or j == 'e' or j == 'i' or j == 'o' or j == 'u':
        new_string.remove(j)
        final = ''.join(new_string)
print('The string after removing the vowels is {}'.format(final))
```

expected output `r` but `reo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
for j in new_string:
    ...
    new_string.remove(...)
```

you are modifying a list while looping on it (see e.g. [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)).

You could simply skip vowels when you create new_list in the first place:

```
for i in letter:
  if not i in 'aeiou':
    new_string.append(i)
final = ''.join(new_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative suggestion:

```
def func(s):
    for c in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        s = ''.join(s.split(c))
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops for this!

```
letter = 'raeiou'
new_string = letter
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
for i in letter:
    if i in vowels:
        new_string = new_string.replace(i,"");
print('The string after removing the vowels is {}'.format(new_string))
```